# What does it mean const type& method

Tags: c++, constants

What does it mean when **const** is a part of the method type

```
const std::string& getName();
```

and when **const** is at the end of the method

```
const std::string& getName() const;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first one is just part of the return type.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the definition of that function cannot modify the structure/class it is part of (i.e. it cannot mutate instance variables).

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int i ;
    void go1 ()
    {
        i = 5 ;
    }
    void go2 () const
    {
        i = 5 ; // error: 'this' is const
    }
} ;
```